# How to use swiper js pagination dots outside of swiper js container in nuxt/vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

**Hi developers,**

I want to use swiper js pagination dots outside of the swiper js container in nuxt js & it will be controlled & clickable, which is how it interacts with the slider.

```
mounted() {
        new Swiper("#swiper-container", {
            // other swiper options
            pagination: {
                el: "#swiper-pagination",
                clickable: true,
            },
        });
    },

 <div id="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.